# How do I read this XML file

Tags: delphi, xml-parsing

I need to read this XML file - extract below...

```
<device xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" dosid="03955" id="" name="PIC18F46Q84" rev="" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PCG.xsd">
    <manager>

    <\manager>      
    <pins>
        <pin name="RE3" wpu="WPUE3" cn="RE3" inlvl="INLVLE3">
            <pinNumber package="46Q84" value="1"/>
            <pinNumber package="QFN40" value="16"/>
            <pinNumber package="TQFP44" value="18"/>
            <pinNumber package="QFN44" value="18"/>
            <pinAlias alias="VPP" module="RESET"/>
            <pinAlias alias="MCLR" module="RESET">
                <constraint name="configBit" type="lock">
                    <constraintVariable name="MCLRE" value="EXTMCLR"/>
                </constraint>
            </pinAlias>
            <pinAlias alias="RE3" module="GPIO"/>
        </pin>
        <pin ansel="ANSELA0" lat="LATA0" name="RA0" od="ODCA0" tris="TRISA0" pps="RA0" ppsValue="0x0" wpu="WPUA0" cn="RA0" slr="SLRA0" inlvl="INLVLA0">
            <pinNumber package="PDIP40" value="2"/>
            <pinNumber package="QFN40" value="17"/>
            <pinNumber package="TQFP44" value="19"/>
            <pinNumber package="QFN44" value="19"/>
            <pinAlias alias="ANA0" module="ADCC"/>
            <pinAlias alias="C1IN0-" module="CMP1"/>
            <pinAlias alias="C2IN0-" module="CMP2"/>
            <pinAlias alias="RA0" module="GPIO"/>
        </pin>
    </pins> 
<\device>
```

I have worked my way down to pins in a for next loop and to pin and to pinNumber (same method).
This is a really basic question, how do I read the items (pin name="RE3" wpu="WPUE3" cn="RE3" inlvl="INLVLE3") and similarly the childNodes and their items e.g. (pinNumber package="PDIP40" value="2"/)

I want to put the Package text into a Combobox, in this case it will be 4 deep.
I want to create a class of Pin which will hold the PinNumber vs Package and the alises for the pin vs Module.

Pins will be a collection of type Pin

I have other tables to extract but if I can get advice on how to extract this basic data I am sure I will be able to continue from there.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for. Are you asking how to read the *attributes* of a given element? Or the *child elements* of a given element? What code are you using right now that you are having trouble with?

Comment: Do you already have setup a structure (record or class) to hold the data from the XML file? If you did, please show it! If you didn't then think about it write the code and ask ANOTHER question if you have some issue.

Comment: Well you use an xml parser. Are you?

Comment: Currently I am not using a parser.  just trying to do everything with TXMLDocument..  I will add my Setup structure tomorrow and add it to the question.

Comment: @JohnBarrat: So in fact you *are* using an XML parser. That's great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some code for you.

The code load the XML file you showed (By the way there are two backslashes where slashes should be) into a list of pins (Class TPins). Each pin is represented by a TPin class which contains the pin data, including two lists for pin number by package and pin alias (TPinNumbers list of TPinNumber and TPinAliases list of TPinAlias).

I made a method to load the XML file. Use is simple:

```
LoadXmlPins('SO67591149.xml');
```

Once loaded, you can do something like this:

```
for Pin in FPins do begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Pin.Name);
    Index := Pin.PinNumbers.FindIndexByPackage(Package);
    if Index >= 0 then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' ' + Package +
                        ' Pin ' + Pin.PinNumbers[Index].Value);
end;
```

Here is the complete code, tested with Delphi 10.4.2:

```
unit XmlPinReaderDemoMain;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
    System.Generics.Collections,
    Xml.XmlIntf, Xml.XmlDoc, Xml.xmldom;

type
    TPinNumber = class
        Package : String;
        Value   : String;
        class function LoadFromXml(NodePinNumber : IXmlNode) : TPinNumber;
    end;

    TPinNumbers = class(TObjectList<TPinNumber>)
       function FindIndexByPackage(const Package : String) : Integer;
    end;

    TPinAlias = class
        Alias  : String;
        Module : String;
        class function LoadFromXml(NodePinAlias : IXmlNode) : TPinAlias;
    end;

    TPinAliases = class(TObjectList<TPinAlias>)
    end;

    TPin = class
        Name     : String;
        Wpu      : String;
        Cn       : String;
        Inlvl    : String;
        Ansel    : String;
        Lat      : String;
        Od       : String;
        Tris     : String;
        Pps      : String;
        PpsValue : String;
        Slr      : String;
        PinNumbers : TPinNumbers;
        PinAliases : TPinAliases;
        constructor Create;
        destructor  Destroy; override;
        class function LoadFromXml(NodePin : IXmlNode) : TPin;
    end;

    TPins = class(TObjectList<TPin>)
        procedure LoadFromXml(NodePins : IXmlNode);
    end;


    TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Memo1: TMemo;
        Button1: TButton;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
        FPins : TPins;
    public
        constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
        destructor  Destroy; override;
        procedure LoadXmlPins(const FileName: String);
        procedure ShowResultDemo;
    end;

function XmlGetAttributeAsString(Node          : IXmlNode;
                                 const AttName : String) : String;

var
    Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

// List all pin and pin number for package 'QFN40'
procedure TForm1.ShowResultDemo;
var
    Pin   : TPin;
    Index : Integer;
const
    Package = 'QFN40';
begin
    if FPins.Count = 0 then begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('No pin found');
        Exit;
    end;
    for Pin in FPins do begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Pin.Name);
        Index := Pin.PinNumbers.FindIndexByPackage(Package);
        if Index >= 0 then
            Memo1.Lines.Add(' ' + Package +
                            ' Pin ' + Pin.PinNumbers[Index].Value);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    LoadXmlPins('SO67591149.xml');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Loaded ' + IntToStr(FPins.Count) + ' pins');
    ShowResultDemo;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadXmlPins(const FileName : String);
var
    XmlDoc       : IXMLDocument;
    NodeDevice   : IXMLNode;
    NodePins     : IXMLNode;
begin
    XmlDoc := TXMlDocument.Create(FileName);
    NodeDevice := XmlDoc.ChildNodes.FindNode('device');
    if not Assigned(NodeDevice) then begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Node ''device'' not found');
        exit;
    end;

    NodePins := NodeDevice.ChildNodes.FindNode('pins');
    if not Assigned(NodePins) then begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Node ''pins'' not found');
        exit;
    end;

    FPins.LoadFromXml(NodePins);
end;

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
    FPins := TPins.Create(TRUE);
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
    FreeAndNil(FPins);
    inherited Destroy;
end;

function XmlGetAttributeAsString(
    Node          : IXmlNode;
    const AttName : String) : String;
begin
    if Node.HasAttribute(AttName) then
        Result := Node.Attributes[AttName]
    else
        Result := '';
end;


{ TPin }

constructor TPin.Create;
begin
    inherited Create;
    PinNumbers := TPinNumbers.Create(TRUE);
    PinAliases := TPinAliases.Create(TRUE);
end;

destructor TPin.Destroy;
begin
    FreeAndNil(PinNumbers);
    FreeAndNil(PinAliases);
    inherited Destroy;
end;

class function TPin.LoadFromXml(NodePin: IXmlNode): TPin;
var
    I         : Integer;
    Node      : IXmlNode;
    PinNumber : TPinNumber;
    PinAlias  : TPinAlias;
begin
    if not Assigned(NodePin) then
        Result := nil
    else begin
        Result           := TPin.Create;
        Result.Name      := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'name');
        Result.Wpu       := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'wpu');
        Result.Cn        := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'cn');
        Result.Inlvl     := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'inlvl');
        Result.Ansel     := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'Ansel');
        Result.Lat       := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'Lat');
        Result.Od        := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'Od');
        Result.Tris      := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'Tris');
        Result.Pps       := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'Pps');
        Result.PpsValue  := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'PpsValue');
        Result.Slr       := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePin, 'Slr');
        for I := 0 to NodePin.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do begin
            Node := NodePin.ChildNodes.Get(I);
            if SameText(Node.NodeName, 'pinNumber') then begin
                PinNumber := TPinNumber.LoadFromXml(Node);
                if Assigned(PinNumber) then
                    Result.PinNumbers.Add(PinNumber);
            end
            else if SameText(Node.NodeName, 'pinAlias') then begin
                PinAlias := TPinAlias.LoadFromXml(Node);
                if Assigned(PinAlias) then
                    Result.PinAliases.Add(PinAlias);
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;

{ TPinNumber }

class function TPinNumber.LoadFromXml(NodePinNumber: IXmlNode): TPinNumber;
begin
    if not Assigned(NodePinNumber) then
        Result := nil
    else begin
        Result := TPinNumber.Create;
        Result.Package := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePinNumber, 'package');
        Result.Value   := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePinNumber, 'value');
    end;
end;

{ TPinAlias }

class function TPinAlias.LoadFromXml(NodePinAlias: IXmlNode): TPinAlias;
begin
    if not Assigned(NodePinAlias) then
        Result := nil
    else begin
        Result := TPinAlias.Create;
        Result.Alias  := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePinAlias, 'alias');
        Result.Module := XmlGetAttributeAsString(NodePinAlias, 'module');
    end;
end;

{ TPins }

procedure TPins.LoadFromXml(NodePins: IXmlNode);
var
    I       : Integer;
    NodePin : IXmlNode;
    Pin     : TPin;
begin
    Clear;
    for I := 0 to NodePins.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do begin
        NodePin := NodePins.ChildNodes.Get(I);
        Pin     := TPin.LoadFromXml(NodePin);
        if Assigned(Pin) then
            Add(Pin);
    end;
end;

{ TPinNumbers }

function TPinNumbers.FindIndexByPackage(const Package: String): Integer;
var
    Index : Integer;
begin
    for Index := 0 to Count - 1 do begin
        if SameText(Package, Items[Index].Package) then begin
            Result := Index;
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
    Result := -1;
end;

end.
```

I coded minimum validity checks. You should probably add more if you want to support possibly bad XML file.

Comment: Wow, I really wasn't expecting that much help but thankyou very much.  I understand better how to use XMLdoc.  I now can use  this as a template for reading other sections of the document.